Crosstab query get price of last date from table
I have three table:
Person

ProductGroup

Price of each ProductGroup for Person with date

I want below result that get price of last date of each ProductGroup

Help me please.
I get result by create table and then set cell by cell
But I want this in one query

Look up "conditional aggregation". If you still need help with your query after looking up the technique you should post data as text instead of images. Why?

If Groups A - C  are numerous or variable, you'll have to look into Dynamic SQL or promote to the presentation layer.

This question is similar to: Get top 1 row of each group. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please don't use images for data, use table markdown .

FYI databases have rows and columns, not cells.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

For logic to select the latest Price for each ProductGroupID and PersonID combination, see Get top 1 row of each group. The general technique is to use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to number the rows within each group, and then filter for row-number = 1.
After you have that, it is just a matter of performing a PIVOT operation.
SELECT PVT.[GROUP C], PVT.[GROUP B], PVT.[GROUP A], PVT.FullName, PVT.PersonId
FROM (
    SELECT PG.ProductGroupName, PGP.Price, P.FullName, P.PersonId
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(PARTITION BY ProductGroupID, PersonID ORDER BY PriceDate DESC)
                AS RowNum
        FROM ProductGroupPrice
    ) PGP
    JOIN ProductGroup PG
        ON PG.ProductGroupID = PGP.ProductGroupID
    JOIN person P
        ON P.PersonID = PGP.PersonID
    WHERE PGP.RowNum = 1
) Q
PIVOT (
    MAX(Q.Price)
    FOR Q.ProductGroupName IN ([GROUP C], [GROUP B], [GROUP A])
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.PersonId

An alternative to using PIVOT is conditional aggregation, where you define select items like MAX(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <value> END) AS <column>.
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN PG.ProductGroupName = 'GROUP C' THEN PGP.Price END) AS [GROUP C],
    MAX(CASE WHEN PG.ProductGroupName = 'GROUP B' THEN PGP.Price END) AS [GROUP B],
    MAX(CASE WHEN PG.ProductGroupName = 'GROUP A' THEN PGP.Price END) AS [GROUP A],
    P.FullName,
    P.PersonId
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY ProductGroupID, PersonID ORDER BY PriceDate DESC)
            AS RowNum
    FROM ProductGroupPrice
) PGP
JOIN ProductGroup PG
    ON PG.ProductGroupID = PGP.ProductGroupID
JOIN person P
    ON P.PersonID = PGP.PersonID
WHERE PGP.RowNum = 1
GROUP BY P.FullName, P.PersonId
ORDER BY P.PersonId

Intermediate results:



ProductGroupName
Price
FullName
PersonId




Group A
250
Karel
1


Group A
120
Ali
3


Group A
100
Emran
4


Group B
150
Karel
1


Group B
200
Jak
2


Group C
150
Karel
1


Group C
100
Jak
2


Group C
105
Hana
5



Final results:



GROUP C
GROUP B
GROUP A
FullName
PersonId




150
150
250
Karel
1


100
200
null
Jak
2


null
null
120
Ali
3


null
null
100
Emran
4


105
null
null
Hana
5



See this db<>fiddle for a demo of both approaches.

thankyou it work. very well

You can use PIVOT to get the results in one query
select 
     isnull(MAX([Group C]),'') as [Group C]
  ,  isnull(MAX([Group B]),'') as [Group B]
  ,  isnull(MAX([Group A]),'') as [Group A]
  ,FullName, PersonID
from
(
SELECT PGP.*, P.FullName, PG.ProductGroupName, CONVERT(varchar(10),Pricedate,112) + '-' + Price as DatePrice
FROM ProductGroupPrice PGP
INNER JOIN ProductGroup PG ON PG.ProductGroupID=PGP.ProductGroupID
INNER JOIN person P ON P.PersonID=PGP.PersonID
) x
pivot
(
  max(DatePrice)
  for ProductGroupName in([Group A], [Group B], [Group C])
)p
  GROUP BY FullName, PersonID

fiddle

That returns max price, i think OP wanted to have last price per date

@siggemannen easy fix. I will just prefix the price with the date. I can then just strip off the first 11 chrs for presentation. I will leave that step for mohammad kermany

You might wanna remove the date again. Also, this won't work if Price is not VARCHAR, which it probably isn't. No need to rush, better make it right
